# Treeptop & Rails where .treeptop files are loaded from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, treetop

I can't seem to find any examples of Treetop in Rails apps.  In a non rails app, when I do Treetop.load('name_of_treetop_file') it looks in the same folder and loads the .treetop file.

In my rails app, no matter where I put it I keep getting:

**No such file or directory - name_of_treetop_.treetop**

Where do I put my .treetop files so I can easily just call .load('name_of_treetop_file')

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I answered my own question in the question itself.

Just need to put the file path relative to the root'

Treetop.load('lib/treetop/name_of_treetop_file')

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use Treetop.load. You can just require Treetop files. Polyglot will load the pre-generated Ruby, or find the treetop file, generate and load it on the fly.